# Check if a table field’s row has a value

Tags: templating, conditional, table-field

We have a table field that has the default value of 1 row when a new entry is published.

Unfortunately, we have

`{% if entry.tableField | length %} display markup and field content... {% endif %}`

and this will always be true of each entry because of the Craft default.

Obviously, we can remove the default row in the future but wondered if there was a way to extend that condition to say, for example

`{% if (entry.tableField | length) and (entry.tableField.row | length) %}`

Comment: What is `entry.tableField.row` meant to say? You want to check if the table field has at least one row and...?

Comment: and has content within one of the row cells

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should do what you're looking for and will work for any number of rows:

```
{% set reallyEmpty = true %}

{% if entry.tableField | length %}
    {# Since you've got a default row set, we're guaranteed that [0] will be set #}
    {% for column in entry.tableField[0] %}
        {% if column|length %}
            {% set reallyEmpty = false %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if reallyEmpty %}
    It's really empty.
{% else %}
    It's not empty.
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
{% if entry.tableField|length and (
      entry.tableField[0].columnHandleOne or
      entry.tableField[0].columnHandleTwo or
      entry.tableField[0].columnHandleThree
   ) %}
```

If there’s only one column that you really care about being filled, you can simplify that to:

```
{% if entry.tableField|length and entry.tableField[0].columnHandle %}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone googling this issue, like I did, you can also just update the `Default Values` in the Table fieldtype and remove the empty row that comes with that fieldtype